# R 3.1.3 'Error attempt to apply non-function' within own designed function to cache an inverse matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix

Hi I am writing a function to cache an inverse matrix to minimise computation time.

I expect that the function will output an inverse matrix however I get an error that says I am attempting to apply a non-function.

The first piece of code creates a function to set up data for the second function. This, in theory takes at matrix inverts it and stores it.

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
    m <- NULL
    set <- function (y) {
      x <<- y
      m <<- NULL
    }
    get <-function() x
    setmatrix <- function(solve) m<<- solve
    getmatrix <- function() m
    list (set=set, get=get, setmatrix=setmatrix, getmatrix=getmatrix)
}
```

I expect no outout at this stage  as I said it just sets up the data. below `casheSolve` takes a matrix and checks it against the data set up in `makeCacheMatrix`

```
cacheSolve <- function(x, ...) {
  m <- x$getmarix()
  if(!is.null(m)){
    message("getting cached data")
    return(m)
  }
  data <- x$get()
  m <- solve(data,...)
  x$setmatrix(m)
  m
  ## Return a matrix that is the inverse of 'x'
}
```

This all enters fine with no errors in my log. I then go to test it and I get an error.

```
n <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
h <- makeCacheMatrix(n)
cacheSolve(h)
```

Error in cacheSolve(h) : attempt to apply non-function

I have a similar function for saving the mean of a vector and that runs error free I am not sure whether I have missed a step in converting it from considering vectors to considering matrixies.

viewing that code may also help to give a better gist so I have included it below

```
makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
  m <- NULL
  set <- function(y) {
    x <<- y
    m <<- NULL
  }
  get <- function() x
  setmean <- function(mean) m <<- mean
  getmean <- function() m
  list(set = set, get = get,
       setmean = setmean,
       getmean = getmean)
}

cachemean <- function(x, ...) {
  m <- x$getmean()
  if(!is.null(m)) {
    message("getting cached data")
    return(m)
  }
  data <- x$get()
  m <- mean(data, ...)
  x$setmean(m)
  m
}

z <- makeVector()
z$set(1:4)
cachemean(z)
```

Comment: Is this `m <- x$getmarix()` a typo?

Comment: user227710 - I am mortified. I'd even printed the code out and marked it up. yes it was a typo and it fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by editing the typo

```
 m <- x$getmarix()
```

should read

```
m <- x$getmatrix()
```

and then the code works fine.

My thanks to user 227710 for noticing this.